# Swift: Closure with receiver like kotlin equivalent?

Tags: swift, lambda, kotlin, closures

Hello I would like to know if there is the equivalent of kotlin lambda with receiver, in swift?

Like this:

```
fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T
```

The `T.()` there is equivalent of this practice in swift?

Comment: What is `T.()`, a static/class function?

Comment: No, there is no equivalent and I actually think it's a good thing. Could you provide some use case? It might be better to find an equivalent of an use case instead of a syntax equivalent.

Comment: @Sulthan `no equivalent and I actually think it's a good thing` that sounds subjective, considering lambda with receiver is quite nice combined with trailing lambdas. Possibly also subjective.

Comment: @Sulthan it's helpful to build DSL, which is extremely handy for UI tests, etc. Check the very end to see how builder pattern can be nicely replaced  with easier to read DSL: https://academy.realm.io/posts/kau-jake-wharton-testing-robots/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Kotlin's *lambda with receiver*, but as far as I read Kotlin docs,

- There's no direct equivalent in Swift
- Same functionality can be achieved by adding a parameter or currying

But, in Swift, you cannot define an extension function on generic `T` where `T` is any type. So, something like your `T.apply` needs to be a global function with two arguments.

With currying, `apply` in Swift would be something like this:

```
func apply<T>(_ this: T, block: (T)->()->T) -> T {
    return block(this)()
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var result = apply("Abc") {this in {this.uppercased()+this.lowercased()}}
print(result) //->ABCabc
```